# How to change user:group for fat32 USB drive?

Tags: linux, usb, permissions

I've formatted a USB drive to fat32 using gparted. I mount it to `/media/usb` which has the following permissions.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 myname users 4096 May 16 11:00 usb/
```

via. `sudo mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/sdb1 /media/usb`. Now the permissions change to:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Dec 31  1969 usb/
```

I run `sudo chown -R myname:users /media/usb`. The output is:

```
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/usb’: Operation not permitted
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

Probably you want to have R/W access to your usb device as a normal user. The problem is, that the FAT filesystem does not implement the concept of file owners, so your chown command (which works e.g. on *ext2/3/4* partitions is doomed to fail).

You have at least two possibilities:

1. Specify the option `user` in the corresponding `fstab` entry, so that a normal user can mount the usb drive:

   ```
    /dev/sdb1     /media/usb      vfat     rw,user       0  0
   ```

   Then use

   ```
    (u)mount /media/usb
   ```

   to (un)mount the media as *myname*.
2. Use the mount options `uid`, `gid` to specify to whom the whole mounted filesystem should belong:

   ```
   sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,uid=myname,gid=users /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Yo cannot directly change Linux permissions on a Microsoft-formatted partition. You **can** do that on an extN partition, because that's a Linux partition which jibes with Linux permissions.

What you *can* do is to change ownership in the corresponding line of */etc/fstab*, which however implies changing it simultaneously for all directories and files within the device. If you want to do that, you may use *uid=1000* for yourself, and *guid=46* for the plugdev groupd, of which all users are automatically members.

The above also applies to NTFS partitions, for exactly the same reason: Microsoft does not really have file and directory permissions.

Comment: Yes I am aware microsoft does not have file and directory permissions - I guess I expected linux to have some-kind of emulating behaviour without actually altering the entries. It's kind of nuts that I can't mount and use a USB drive without doing research.

Comment: @user3467349 That's not true: your drive is ready to be mounted as it is. What you cannot do is to treat it like a more advanced, Linux file system, that's all.

Comment: Yeah but that linux decides I need `root` access to `r/w` to it rather than user level access is also quite arbitrary, no? So if it can make one presumption (which is not reflective of the underlying file-system) why not also be able to change the presumption?

Comment: @user3467349 You are able to change the presumption:  like I said above, use *uid=1000* in fstab, and voilà you are the owner of all files and directory. The *presumption* you mention is the fact that the default is the umask of the current process, and since you must be mounting the device as root, it naturally inherits the ownership of root. But you can change it, as above. Also, you may write to the device as root, since everything will be forgotten on a Windows system.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that. I guess an even simpler solution in that case is to use a non-root mounting option such as `udisks`.

Comment: Well Microsoft _do_ have file and directory permissions in NTFS, but they have a format very different from that of POSIX permissions. See also [ntfs-3g ownership and permissions page](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/). There it is explained how to setup an NTFS partition to use POSIX permissions in Linux.

Comment: Would you mind adding use of udisks or another user-space mounting tool to your answer? I'd like the accepted answer to have an easily accessible method listed, rather than requiring others to read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The default non-root user *does not* have default access to block devices. *If* this is  truly needed do one the following:

```
mount -t vfat  -o rw /dev/sdXY /run/media/$username/foo
## /media/.gvfs/$username/foo for ubuntu) 

mount -t vfat -o rw  /dev/sdXY /home/$username/foo
```

Add said user to `Plugdev` group.

Then, add or create a `udev` auto mount script in `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-usb-rules`

```
mountpoint  by /dev/sdXY ,  /dev/by-uuid/ ,   /dev/by-device (using the usb-x-y notation)
```

Comment: I don't think you are correct. The same operations I gave in my example work perfectly for an `ext4` formatted device. It might be some peculiarity of fat32/vfat, but then my question is still unanswered.

Comment: vfat and ntfs DON'T have this concept of ownership and permission like linux / mac do so changing them is futile.  @Marius explains how to do it in the same way I personally prefer the command line

Comment: That might be true, but your answer regarding block devices is not relevant in this case.

Comment: Yes a usb is a block device, but the problem I am having is *only relevant* to fat/vfat formatted block devices. You should update your answer to be useful for future readers instead of insulting people.

Comment: It is useful as is,  And its the format you chose causing issues and any amount of pre-action research would have told you that ... my answer is a one time change to /etc/fstab as was mentioned by another answer dude learn to use a system.

Comment: Telling someone they're an idiot is insulting. If you continue to engage in this kind of behavior, you will be suspended. Also, please take care of formatting your posts properly using code syntax.